# ASP NET MVC PREVIOUS PAGE

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, i am having 3 pages. how to display previous page with already selected value on clicking back button from one page. (eg dropdown,radiobutton, button selected)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add some more information

Comment: For the simplest way, you should use TempData to fill your actions in Tempdata and use that values for Back button.